# Copy entire list using Powershell CSOM sharepoint

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I need to export an entire list as a .csv file. I actually have this code which works great but I need to write each column I want to export:

```
$listTitle = "Example"
$list = $ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle($listTitle);
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery;
$query.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Counter'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query></View>"
$listItems = $list.GetItems($query);
$ctx.Load($listItems);
$ctx.ExecuteQuery();
$tableau =@();
foreach ($listItem in $listItems)
{
    $result = new-object psobject
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Title -value $listItem['Title'];
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Description -value $listItem['Description'];
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Age -value $listItem['Age'];
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Sexe -value $listItem['Sexe'];
    $tableau += $result;
}
$CsvName2 = "Export_"+$ListTitle.replace(' ','_')+".csv"
$tableau | export-csv $CsvName2 -notype;
```

The part I want to improve is the foreach loop:

```
foreach ($listItem in $listItems)
{
    $result = new-object psobject
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Title -value $listItem['Title'];
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Description -value $listItem['Description'];
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Age -value $listItem['Age'];
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Sexe -value $listItem['Sexe'];
    $tableau += $result;
}
```

I want the script collects all columns but I don't know how to do it...

I got this advice: Replace my loop with:

```
foreach ($listItem in $listItems)
{
    $result = new-object psobject
    foreach ($field in $listItem.Fields) 
    {
        if ($field.Hidden -eq $false)
        {
            $result | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name $field.Title -value $listItem[$field.InternalName]; 
        }
    }
    $tableau += $result;
}
```

But all I got is a blank file. I don't really understand structure of list/filed items.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just a comment : The same can be achieved with the help of **Export to Excel** option available on **Library Tab** of Documents library.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your advice.
But the aim of this script is to be able to do a complete save automatically.